# visual basic 2010 text file not in bin/debug folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text

I am trying to get a text file to display in a `listbox`, but I can't see it when I check the bin/debug folder and can't get anything to display. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file properties in vs 2010, select "Copy to Output Directory" either "Copy Always" or "Copy if Newer".

Comment: No, the problem is that I can't see the file in the solution explorer so I can't do what you suggested.